# javascript- Is Date.now a nested function within the Date function?

Tags: javascript

I see from my console that Date is a function, (`typeof Date`  shows function). And Date.now is a function.

I'm aware that a function Date()  could have within it `var now=function....` But then `now` wouldn't be accessible from outside, it'd just be local. And it could say `this.now` but then now would only exist when Date() is called with new. I can see that typeof Date is a string and typeof new Date() is an object.  So `Date` is a function.. So I can't see how it is that I can do Date.now

I see 'now' listed on mdn for the Date object, but I don't see where it would be placed in the native code e.g. if one were to write an object Blah, with function called with Blah.func  where would we place the definition of func?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function is also an object, so it can have properties like any other object, and a property can have a function as value.

The `now` property is not inside the function, it's attached to the function object. If you would repeat that in code you would use:

```
function Date() {
  // some code
}

Date.now = function(){
  // some code
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`now` is a method on the `Date` object, which happens to be a function, but function objects can have properties just like other objects.

Comment: i just found out also that "somestring".aaa=4;  works but "somestring" is a primitive not an object, and it is being converted into an object. And even when doing  var a="asdf";  a.aaa=4;  console.log(a.aaa) it is undefined, as 'a' is converted to an object whose property then lost with the object, as the converted object isn't assigned anywhere..

Comment: You accepted a semi-identical answer which was posted after this one.

Comment: it's not semi-identical 'cos his had code and 'cos at the time when I had the question, I didn't know that the function was created with `Date.now=`  (Also, as a side point, at the time I posted the question, I had the answer and intended to post it, and did, so if you look at my answer to my own question, you'll get a good idea of what I looked for as an answer, but I saw some answers had been posted even before i'd posted the answer to my own question.. and Guffa had got to the main point of any answer, which was `Date.now=function`

Comment: `Date.now = function` is **precisely** identical to saying "a method on the `Date` object". Actually, it's **more** accurate to say "a method on the `Date` object", because `Date.now = function` is **not** how `now` is implemented; among other things, it's implemented in a way which is non-enumerable.

Comment: You make a good point..  I have now updated my answer based on what you have said.  If you were to make your answer as comprehensive, in terms of code/explanation, as my answer then I will likely change (more than consider changing) the accepted answer from Guffa to you.

Answer (score 1):

I think @Guffa's answer is correct, but i'd like to provide other example.

If i've understood you right, you ask about next behavior:

```
var blah = function() {

};

blah.now = function() {
    new Date();
};
```

Check types:

```
console.log(typeof blah);     // function
console.log(typeof blah.now); // function
```

Answer (score 0):

function is an object

typeof function(){}  says "function"  though function is an object

`(function(){}) instanceof Object` <-- returns true

And so you can say it'd be that outside the Date constructor function there'd be a line that says Date.now=function(){...}

which assigns the Date function object a property.

It's a bit like java's static. But it's different because javascript doesn't have classes and it actually belongs to the Date object,  Date is an instance of Object.  Also it's quite unlike java's static, because the instances of Date can't access the property unless they do Date.xyz  Similarly, since you are in the window object, you can't create xyz by just typing var xyz=function(){..}  you have to do  `Date.now=function(){..}`

**ADDED**

more accurate is if the function has a name since `Date.now` returns `function now()`  So instead of `Date.now=function(){...}`, it'd be more accurate to say   `Date.now=function now(){...}`  but one can be more accurate than that..

since also

(based on an idea mentioned by torazaburo)

Torazaburo points out that Date's `now` function is not enumerable. So I suppose one would define it with Object.defineProperty like so.

```
Object.defineProperty(Date,'noww',{enumerable:false, value:function noww(){}})<ENTER>
```

that creates the property with the value.

When a property is enumerable you have to create it with the value there, rather than assign it later. (trying to assign to an enumerable:false property will just give undefined.

So now we've created the noww function very much like Date (though no body 'cos the functionality within the function wasn't really the question).

```
Date.noww<ENTER> 
function noww()  <--- like if I'd entered Date.now<ENTER>

Date.propertyIsEnumerable('noww');
false  <-- like if i'd entered Date.propertyisEnumerable('now')

Date.propertyIsEnumerable('now');
false

Date.hasOwnProperty('now');
true

Date.hasOwnProperty('noww');
true
```